# How to create node on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

After connected to AgensGraph.

I try to create node on AgensGraph.

But, there is a error on action.

```
kurt=# create (:v{id:1});
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
```

How to set graph_path?

Answer (score 0):

You must create graph, before create vertex(node).

```
assam=# create graph new_graph;
CREATE GRAPH
```

After creating graph, set graph_path.

```
assam=# set graph_path = new_graph;
SET
```

Finally, You can create a vertex(node).

```
assam=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
assam=# match (n:v) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 v[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)
```